# Using delay(0) in combination with refCount()

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

[This article describes the refCount operator](https://blog.angularindepth.com/rxjs-understanding-the-publish-and-share-operators-16ea2f446635) and explains that in order to prevent the unsubscription of obervable A we have to add `delay(0)` to the source observable such that th        import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";

```
    const source = Observable.defer(() => Observable.of(
    Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)
    )).delay(0);
```

Is `0` always enough?  In other words does passing zero guarantee that the notification will be delayed until all `m.subscribe()` statements have run, assuming they are all run immediately following the `multicast` statement like this:

```
const m = source.multicast(() => new Subject<number>()).refCount();
m.subscribe(observer("a"));
m.subscribe(observer("b"));
```

In the above case we are only subscribing observers `a` and `b`.  If we subscribed a million observers after the multicast statement would running `delay(0)` still guarantee taht they all will be subscribed before the first source notification happens?

Comment: I've had problems with `delay(0)` it does not work the same as `setTimeout(..., 0)` and the reason (I think..) is that the default scheduler is using `setInterval(..., 0)` which has a different behavior, because the specs say that the shortest allowed interval in JS is 10ms. Where as, `setTimeout(..., 0)` means to run immediately in the next digest. So they aren't exactly the same thing, but I am not sure if this has any effect on your question. It's just a FYI.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To understand the issue you must know that:

- Javascript is single threaded;
- Asynchronous events runs in event loop (a.k.a. Micro Task and Macro Task)
- When Async event happens, it is added to the Event loop;
- After async event added to the Event loop, Javascript continues with synchronous code;
- After no synchronous code left, it runs events code from Event loop.

This Observable would be synchronous if you wouldn't add `delay(0)`:

```
const source = Observable.defer(() => Observable.of(
Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)
)).delay(0);
```

When first Subscription happens (subscribing is synchronous code), Observable emits immediately, because it is also synchronous. But if you add `delay(0)` (similar to `setTimeout`), Javascript will wait until all synchronous code (all `source.subscribe()` in this case), are executed. After that it will run asynchronous `delay(0)`).

And here:

```
const m = source.multicast(() => new Subject<number>()).refCount();
m.subscribe(observer("a"));
m.subscribe(observer("b"));
```

You have `source` Observable which becomes asynchronous after its emition is passed to `delay(0)`. At that point, synchronous code will continue (all your other `source.subscribe()` calls) and after they are done, synchronous `delay(0)` will emit.

So it is safe even for millions `source.subscribe()` calls to get executed in this case.

p.s.

*`multicast(() => new Subject<number>()).refCount()` is exactly the same as `share()` - it takes **multicast** with **Subject** factory and counts active subscriptions with `refCount`.*

Comment: Thanks - Great answer!!